# CMD+Option+D simulation in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, api, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to simulate a CMD+Option+D key press simultaneously. I've done all kind of looking and the best way so far I've seen is to do this:

```
CGEventSourceRef src =
    CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);

    CGEventRef cmdd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, kVK_Command, true);
    CGEventRef cmdu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, kVK_Command, false);
    CGEventRef optd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, kVK_Option, true);
    CGEventRef optu = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, kVK_Option, false);
    CGEventRef dd = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, kVK_ANSI_D, true);
    CGEventRef du = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(src, kVK_ANSI_D, false);

    CGEventSetFlags(dd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand); //NO idea why this is here.
    CGEventSetFlags(du, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand); //NO idea why this is here.


    CGEventTapLocation loc = kCGHIDEventTap; // kCGSessionEventTap also works
    CGEventPost(loc, cmdd); //Cmd down
    CGEventPost(loc, optd); //Option down
    CGEventPost(loc, dd);   //D down
    CGEventPost(loc, cmdu); //Cmd up
    CGEventPost(loc, optu); //Option up
    CGEventPost(loc, du);   //D up

    CFRelease(cmdd);
    CFRelease(cmdu);
    CFRelease(optd);
    CFRelease(optu);
    CFRelease(dd);
    CFRelease(du);
    CFRelease(src);
```

However, doing this does not toggle the dock like it does when I use my keyboard? Why is this? What am I doing wrong? I imported Carbon.h, so it seems like this should work?

Comment: where have you got kVK_Option? I can't even try to run your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
// as before ...
CGEventSetFlags(dd, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand ^ kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate); 
CGEventSetFlags(du, kCGEventFlagMaskCommand ^ kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate);
// continues...
```

I think you have to set both the command *and* alternate (option key) flags for the D event.

Comment: Or `kCGEventFlagMaskCommand | kCGEventFlagMaskAlternate`, the difference being that if either of the masks has a bit in common with the other (unlikely in this case, but possible in others, such as when using one of the LSOpen functions), `^` will unset that bit whereas `|` won't. You probably don't want any bits that are set in both masks to get unset when you combine them, so `|` is usually the right choice.

Comment: What I don't get is why you have to combine the explicit keydowns WITH the flags, and just doing one or the other doesn't work on its own.

Comment: @iluvcapra: Menu population responds to changes in the modifiers (e.g., to reveal hidden alternate items), which would be the explicit modifier key-downs, whereas menu item searches use the modifier mask from the event. By the way, you might want to send the D key up event before the modifier key up events, just in case it matters somewhere.